# Как загнать картинку под шапку сайта?

Tags: html, css, позиционирование

Вот мой макет

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как загнать оранжевую картинку под шапку сайта?

Так же при добавлении контента у меня летит вся верстка, хотя для header'a четко указаны границы (100рх высота).

В чем мои ошибки? Если не трудно, подскажите, пожалуйста.

Заранее спасибо!

```css
body {
  width: 1680px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

header {
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: rgba(248, 248, 248, 0.1);
  display: flex;
}

.menu_block {
  padding-top: 22px;
  padding-bottom: 22px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.menu a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #2f3c4d;
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 500;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.menu a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.menu li {
  margin-right: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.menu li:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}

.logo img {
  margin-right: 320px;
  margin-left: 270px;
}

.button a {
  line-height: 14px;
  display: block;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #ffffff;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 18px 35px;
  background: #ff7340;
  border-radius: 25px;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-top: 25px;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
  margin-left: 160px;
  margin-right: 260px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.text_live {}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="menu_block">
    <div class="logo">
      <a href="#"><img class="logo_img" src="https://i.postimg.cc/BvJbtVhY/logo.png" alt=""></a>
    </div>
    <div class="menu">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="/about">about</a></li>
        <li><a href="/meeting">meet us</a></li>
        <li><a href="/gallery">gallery</a></li>
        <li><a href="/blog">blog</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="button">
    <a href="/adventures">adventures</a>
  </div>

  <div class="live_block">
    <div class="text_live">
      <h1>Live your <span class="adv_style">adventure</span></h1>
      <div class="text_live">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</div>
      <div class="btn_live">
        <a href="#">Take me there</a>
      </div>
      <div class="img_orange">
        <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/TYQHZyzK/bg.png" alt="">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: `position: absolute; z-index: -1`

Comment: Это вот прям `header`? Я думаю в верстке идёт блок, внутри которого есть шапка и intro блок

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для того чтобы поместить один элемент под другой нужно отталкиваться от концепции [контекста наложения](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context). Если элемент имеет позицию отличную от `static`, то к нему применим [z-index](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/Adding_z-index), свойство позволяющее перемещать элемент выше или ниже относительно его текущего "слоя".

Ниже простой пример применения вышеописанного на примере Вашего исходного кода:

```css
body {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

header { 
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  height: 100px;
}

.menu_block {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  background-color: rgba(248, 248, 248, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
  padding-top: 22px;
  padding-bottom: 22px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.menu a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #2f3c4d;
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 500;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.menu a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.menu li {
  margin-right: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.menu li:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}

.logo img {
  margin-right: 32px;
  margin-left: 27px;
}

.button a {
  line-height: 14px;
  display: block;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #ffffff;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 18px 35px;
  background: #ff7340;
  border-radius: 25px;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-top: 25px;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 26px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.img_orange {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: #ff7340;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 30px;
  z-index: -1;
}

.live_block {
  margin: 70px 40px 0;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="menu_block">
    <div class="logo">
      <a href="#"><img class="logo_img" src="https://i.postimg.cc/BvJbtVhY/logo.png" alt=""></a>
    </div>
    <div class="menu">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="/about">about</a></li>
        <li><a href="/meeting">meet us</a></li>
        <li><a href="/gallery">gallery</a></li>
        <li><a href="/blog">blog</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="button">
      <a href="/adventures">adventures</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="img_orange"></div>
</header>

  <div class="live_block">
    <div class="text_live">
      <h1>Live your <span class="adv_style">adventure</span></h1>
      <div class="text_live">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</div>
      <div class="btn_live">
        <a href="#">Take me there</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Нужно сделать родительской блок, у которого будет `position: relative`, внутри этого блока вы можете создать `position: absolute` элемент, давать им разные `z-index` и они будут вставать в нужной очередности.
В данном примере я использовал псевдоэлемент `::after` к блоку `.intro`, у которого стоит `position:relative`. Псевдоэлементу я задал `postion: absolute` и `z-index: -1`, таким образом, он стал ниже всех других элементов.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@400;700&display=swap');
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

:root {
  --orange: #F87A4C;
}

img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
}

body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

.container {
  max-width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 20px;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

header {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background-color: rgba(248, 248, 248, 0.3);
  padding: 10px 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
  font-weight: bold;
}

header a {
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 2px;
  --colorLine: black;
}

header a::before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: var(--colorLine);
  transform-origin: left;
  transition: transform 0.2s linear;
}

header a:hover::before {
  transform: scaleX(0)
}

.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  background-color: var(--orange);
  padding: 10px 15px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition-property: color, background-color, border-color;
  transition-duration: 0.2s;
  transition-timing-function: linear;
  border: 2px solid transparent;
}

.btn:hover {
  color: black;
  border-color: var(--orange);
  background-color: white;
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
}

.header__container {
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.header__container>*:not(:last-child) {
  margin-right: 20px;
}

nav.header__menu>*:not(:last-child) {
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.header__logo {
  --width: 30px;
  min-width: var(--width);
  max-width: var(--width);
}

.header__right>a {
  --colorLine: white;
  color: white;
}

.intro {
  min-height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  flex-direction: column;
  z-index: 1;
}

.intro::before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: var(--orange);
  z-index: -1;
  border-radius: 0 0 0 100px;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.intro>.intro__preview {
  flex: 1;
  padding: 10px 0;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}

.intro__preview__container {
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.intro__preview__container>*:not(:last-child) {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.intro__h1 {
  font-size: 50px;
}

.intro__h1 span {
  color: var(--orange);
  text-transform: uppercase;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<section class="intro flex">
  <header>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="header__container flex">
        <div class="header__logo">
          <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/BvJbtVhY/logo.png">
        </div>
        <nav class="header__menu flex">
          <a href="">About</a>
          <a href="">Meet us</a>
          <a href="">Gallery</a>
          <a href="">Blog</a>
        </nav>
        <div class="header__right">
          <a href="">Adventures</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>
  <div class="intro__preview flex">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="intro__preview__container flex">
        <h1 class="intro__h1">Live your <span>adventure</span></h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Necessitatibus aliquam cum optio suscipit eligendi voluptatem odio in. Excepturi, ut.</p>
        <a href="" class="btn">Take me there</a>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```